# How to add a new page next to Settings in Template Studio for WinUI

Tags: winui-3, navigationview

I want to have a few pages at the bottom of navigation pane but I can not find in code where the Settings navigation is added. Do you have any advice?

[image: canNotTrackSettingsNavigationElement]

There is a documentation for NavigationView

https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview

Look for "Footer menu items"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [Footer menu items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview#:%7E:text=Settings%20button%20(optional)-,Footer%20menu%20items,-You%20can%20use).

```xml
<NavigationView>
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu item 1" />
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu item 2" />
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <NavigationView.FooterMenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Footer menu item 1" />
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Footer menu item 2" />
    </NavigationView.FooterMenuItems>
</NavigationView>
```

By the way, you can also add items to [Pane footer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview#:%7E:text=the%20footer%20menu.-,Pane%20footer,-You%20can%20place) but they are not included in the selection process, so you can click them but they won't change the selection.

Comment: So, problems solved? or you need to go further and place ``NavigationViewItems`` below the **Settings**? (which I have never tried.)

Comment: It works. It is described here https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview find 'Footer menu items'

Comment: Great! Then can you mark this as accepted and close this question?